# How can I fix this undefined variable problem on laravel-8?

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-8

I'm having trouble with one of the pages in my app, its a library type app, and i want to display the publishers. However my code seems to either be bugged or there is something i'm missing.

Please help, it would be much appreciated.

I tried this, but it didn't work

(PublisherController.php)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class PublisherController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $publish = DB::table('book_publishers')->get();
        return view('publisher', compact('publish'));
    }
}
```

(publisher.blade.php)

```
@extends('layouts.template')

@section('content')
    <div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center">
        <h2>Book Details</h2>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center">
        @foreach ($publish as $pubs)
            <div class="card m-4" style="width: 18rem;">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <img src={{$pubs->image_url}} class="card-img-top" height="386px">
                </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
    
                    <h5 class="card-title">{{$pubs->title}}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text text-success">by</p>
                    <p class="card-text">{{$pubs->author}}</p>
    
                    <div class="d-flex">
                        <a type="submit" class="btn btn-danger mx-4" href="/publisher">Details</a>
                    </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    
    </div>
@endsection
```

(Web.php)

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\BookController;
use App\Http\Controllers\PublisherController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', [BookController::class, 'index']);

Route::get('/contact', function () {
    return view('contact');
});

Route::get('/publisher', [PublisherController::class, 'index']);

Route::get('/category', function(){
    return view('category');
});
```

(Error Message)

ErrorException
Undefined variable $publish (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\UTSWebProg\resources\views\publisher.blade.php)

Comment: "*Error Message when I ran the page*" - which page?  How did you "run" it, do yo mean a GET request in your browser?  Have you tried `dd($publish)` in your method to check you're really hitting the right route/method?

Comment: When i tried running the publisher page, it displayed the error message instead, yes the GET request is what I mean. And no I haven't yet, I'm fairly new to php web programming sorry.

Comment: *'When i tried running the publisher page...'*: Was it through the web browser? If so, with what URL?

Comment: When you add a `dd($publish)` in your controller method, does it show ?

Comment: Yes, i executed it through a web browser via php artisan serve with http://127.0.0.1:8000/publisher. As for dd($publish), it showed me something about an Illuminate\Support\Collection? Maybe that can help a bit?

Comment: Does it help that my publisher page also uses a model that has a 1-M relationship?